# batch copy paste google-apps-script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there an efficient method to batch copy paste an entire array range, not necessarily an active range, in Google Sheets, using a Google script using the values only paste parameter?

I have only found inefficient methods to evaluate an array row by row, and these exceed execution times on large arrays.

Comment: Could you maybe provide some code you've already write ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to copy an entire array range, such as from A1 to B4 (two rows, 4 columns), you can use the **copyTo** function in Google App Script to copy and paste this entire range while preserving formatting.

Some example code would be nice however.